# EntityFramework's ObjectStateEntry.GetModifiedProperties in 3 tier scenario

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework 4 with self-tracking entities in a 3 tier scenario. 
My goals is  to detect the modified properties in the ObjectContext's SavingChanges handler when the entity gets saved back to the server.

Note that:

- this is a 3-tier scenario; so the Self-Tracked Entity is saved in another ObjectContext than the one it was fetched from

  the Self-Tracked Entity is attached to the context before calling SaveChanges, and that 
  all changes are saved as expected.

Here's what I do to track the modified properties:

```
var objectStateManager = objectContext.ObjectStateManager;
var modifiedObjectStateEntries = objectStateManager
                    .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified)
                    .Where(x => !x.IsRelationship);
foreach (var modifiedObjectStateEntry in modifiedObjectStateEntries)
{
    // need to refresh from datasource, since this entity was fetched in another context
    objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, modifiedObjectStateEntry.Entity);
    var modifiedProperties = modifiedObjectStateEntry.GetModifiedProperties();
}
```

Now, for some reason, the modifiedProperties collection contains all properties, not just
the ones that were modified. Any idea why this is the case?

When I compare OriginalValues to CurrentValues, everything looks as expected.

```
var originalValues = modifiedObjectStateEntry.OriginalValues;
var currentValues = modifiedObjectStateEntry.CurrentValues;
for (int i = 0; i < originalValues.FieldCount; i++)
{
    // this works fine, only diffs are detected
    if (!Equals(originalValues.GetValue(i), currentValues.GetValue(i)))
    {
    }
}
```

Any idea why the "modifiedObjectStateEntry.GetModifiedProperties();" would not work as I expected in this case?

Thanks for your time, 
Koen

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? What is the point of using self-tracking entities when you don't use `ApplyChanges`?

Comment: I do am calling ApplyChanges.

I'm doing this for auditing purposes to track what properties have changed. I do not want to depend on STE's ChangeTracker to do this kind of audit tracing, because not everything gets saved via a 3-tier STE scenario in this app.

Comment: Can you please show the code used for attaching entities back to the server-side context?

Comment: Those entities are attached by Microsoft's Self-Tracking Entities generated extension method "ApplyChanges" in "SelfTrackingEntitiesContextExtensions":

objectContext.People.ApplyChanges(person);

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of is that you are modifing all the properties because they will only show as a return from that method if they were changed after the last SaveChanges were issued.

As you can see on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.getmodifiedproperties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it stated:
**Returns the names of an object's properties that have changed since the last time SaveChanges was called**.

Looking at your code example the reason you are seeing this is because you are refreshing the entity (this will set every property and mark them as modified).

```
...    
objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, modifiedObjectStateEntry.Entity);
...
```

This call will reset all properties not just the ones that were modified.

It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve however if it is to see what was updated you cant do it like this. You will need to make a copy of the entity and refresh only then you can check for the modified fields but it would be ugly.